# iOS iCloud failing to write with, Couldn't get container configuration from the server error

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, icloud

I have one app that I wrote already reading from and writing to the iCloud. I am essentially using the same code in my new app to do the same thing, but for some reason it will not work, giving me the following error, "Couldn't get container configuration from the server". Let me clarify, with this new app it does puts an entry in iCloud under manage storage, but instead of being under the name of my app, it is under adhoc.
[image: iCloud Image]

Here is the line in my info.Plist,
[image: Info.plist]

Here is the line from my Entitlements,plist
[image: Entitlements.plist]

lastly, here is my identifier defined on the apple developer site,
[image: Apple Identifier]

I have verified and reverified that everything is pointing to the correct thing so I am baffled. Any help would be much appreciated.

**EDIT** I guess what it is doing is writing file to my phone, but when it goes to save data to it, it fails with this message, Here is my call to save the data.

```
CKRecordID recordID = new CKRecordID(strDate);
await Task.Delay(200);
// Save it to iCloud                                                    
await pvc.SaveToiCloud(newRecord);
```

Here is my code to save the record,

```
public async Task SaveToiCloud(CKRecord newRecord)
    {
        ThisApp.PrivateDatabase.SaveRecord(newRecord, (record, err) =>
        {
```

**Edit:**

I was thinking that possibly the number of nodes I had was too many, so I took out the "dist" one you see below, but that did not help. I thought maybe that was why I was seeing module name of adhoc under icloud on my phone, but I guess I was wrong.

Old:
[image: iCloud nodes]

New:
[image: New iCloud nodes]

**Edit**

I have been doing more digging and found that this line of code is actually the one throwing the error.

```
File.WriteAllText(Path.Combine(filePath.Path, name + date), "Test");
```

The name and date contain correct values and the path looks fine to me... I guess... Don't know actually how it should look. Here is how the file path is getting set right above this call,

```
NSUrl filePath = NSFileManager.DefaultManager.GetUrlForUbiquityContainer(null).Append("Documents", true);
```

If anyone could offer any advice, I would be most appreciative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I finally figured out the issue and it works like a champ now. The issue was the case in my bundle id in my info.plist. In CloudKit the DB name was all lower case, but my bundle Id in my info.plist, had AdHoc as my last node instead of adhoc as was in the CloudKit. You might say, what does the bundle Id have to do with the iCloud name, and actually I am not really sure, but I noticed that it was taking the case of that last node from my Bundle Id, not the case specified in the iCloud definition as I have shown above. Hope this helps someone who is struggling with a similar issue Have a great day!